# Facing some error while generating session for ICICI Breeze using Java SDK

Tags: java, breeze

While trying to generate the breeze connect session using Java SDK, shows some error as provided below..

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: org.apache.http.ConnectionClosedException: Premature end of Content-Length delimited message body (expected: 574; received: 416)

```java
import com.breeze.breezeconnect.BreezeConnect;

public class BreezeMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BreezeConnect bc = new BreezeConnect(Get.API_KEY);
        bc.generateSession(Get.API_SEC_KEY, token);
    }
}
```